# How can I update Zustand state using Immer with objects added in form controlled by React-Hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I am struggling with Zustand and Immer using React-Hook-Form. I want to register a set of values from the form into a list, then be able to add new objects into that list.

Scenario: User enters a single parcels data into the form, then clicks button to save it to memory (state, managed by Zustand and Immer). Object is then added to a list of orders (array), and can then add more parcels to this list before sending it to backend.

I need help with the part that adds the extra parcel to the list (named addParcel here). The idea is that 'setParcel' creates the first object, and then 'addParcel' adds additional parcels to the list. The list is rendered with Object map-function.

The error message say that 'draft is not a function'.

This is the userStore that handles the logic, it is imported to main component.

```
import create from "zustand";
import { produce } from "immer";
import { SingleParcel } from "../type/User";

type ParcelQuoteState = {
  parcel: SingleParcel;
  setParcel: (input: SingleParcel) => void;
  addParcel: (input: SingleParcel) => void;
  removeParcel: () => void;
};

export const useParcelStore = create<ParcelQuoteState>((set) => ({
  parcel: Object.create({}),
  setParcel: (input: SingleParcel) => {
    set((state) => ({
      parcel: Object.assign(state.parcel, input),
    }));
  },
  addParcel: (input: SingleParcel) => {
    set(
      produce((parcel) => {
        draft.parcel.push({
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
          data: input,
        });
      })
    );
  },
  removeParcel: () => {
    set((state) => ({
      parcel: Object.assign(state.parcel, null),
    }));
  },
}));
```

This is what the SingleParcel type looks like,

```
export type SingleParcel = {
  parcelID: string | undefined;
  parcelWeight_kg: number | undefined;
  parcelHeight_cm: number | undefined;
  parcelWidth_cm: number | undefined;
  parcelLength_cm: number | undefined;
  parcelVolume_m3: number | undefined;
  parcelAmount: number | undefined;
  parcelAvailableTime: string | undefined;
  parcelDeliveryTime: string | undefined;
  parcelStartStreet: string;
  parcelStartStreetNumber: number | undefined;
  parcelStartAreaCode: number | undefined;
  parcelStartCity: string | undefined;
  parcelDestinationStreet: string | undefined;
  parcelDestinationStreetNumber: number | undefined;
  parcelDestinationAreaCode: number | undefined;
  parcelDestinationCity: string | undefined;
};
```

References,

- Zustand: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand
- Immer: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce
- React-Hook-Form: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve the 'addParcel' byt changing the Draft to Parcel directly. Instead of pushing data to a secondary state, I push changes to the global state. It seems that it uses Object instead of Array. Data comes out as intended.

userStore.ts

```
addParcel: (input: SingleParcel) => {
    set(
      produce((state) => {
        state.parcel.push({
          parcelID: short.generate(),
          parcelData: input,
        });
      })
    );
  },
```